# Rails 5.1 w/ Webpacker cannot find assets while working via local wifi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, iphone, localhost, ruby

I'm using Rails 5.1 with the Webpacker configuration that is now by default integrated in Rails. I've followed [this article](https://medium.com/@hpux/rails-5-1-loves-javascript-a1d84d5318b) "Rails 5.1 loves Javascript" to get me on the right track.

So far so good. If run `rails s` on a shell and `./bin/webpack-dev-server --host 127.0.0.1` I can work on the application locally on my desktop.

### The issue appears when I try to debug on iphone via my local wifi.

The phone can connect to the local machine via port 3000 and browse the entire application, but apparently it cannot find `127.0.0.1:8080` server and therefore the webpack bundle. Infact it throws this error:

> Failed to load resources: cannot connect to server http://127.0.0.1:8080/packs/application.js

I've already tried running `./bin/webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0` but I get the same error.

How do I need to set webpack-dev-server so Rails can load webpack resources?

I've also opened an [issue](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/797) on the official github of rails/webpacker.

Answer (score 0):

My bad, everything works fine, I just didn't know I needed to connect to the local machine IP. Basically `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` aren't accessible outside the local machine. Therefore you need to explicitly declare which is the host when exposing Webpack dev server.

Adding the machine IP (which was `192.168.1.7`) I've been able to connect:

`./bin/webpack-dev-server --host 192.168.1.7`